# How to and retrieving JSON data from a server

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I am taking an online course and one of the things we have to do is print out the JSON entries from localhost:8080/tasks. when i go to localhost:8080, it is supposed to run this code below. However, when i run it i get this response:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Sat Dec 03 19:04:16 EST 2016
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Exception parsing document: template="tasks", line 28 - column 42

column 42 is

> if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Tasks</h2>

    <!-- TODO: add the ability to list tasks -->
    <ul id="tasks">
    </ul>


    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="addTask();" value="Add!"/>
    </form>

    <!-- the javascript has been embedded to the same site -->
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        // The URL to the application server that holds the tasks.
        var url = "localhost:8080/tasks";

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        var liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.name));
        document.querySelector("#tasks").appendChild(liElement);
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        function loadTasks() {
        }

        function addTask() {
        var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
        if (!name) {
        return;
        }

        console.log(name);

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        var data = new Object();
        data.name = name;

        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState === 4) {
        if (http.status === 200) {
        addTaskToList(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
        }
        }
        }

        http.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }


        function addTaskToList(task) {
        var liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.name));
        document.querySelector("#tasks").appendChild(liElement);
        }


        window.onload = function () {
        loadTasks();
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

why is this happening?

Tasks:

```
    package sec.domain;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Task {

private String id;
private String name;

public Task() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Tasks controller:

```
package sec.controller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import sec.domain.Task;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class TaskController {

private List<Task> tasks;

public TaskController() {
    this.tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Task fixme = new Task();
    fixme.setName("Fix me.");
    this.tasks.add(fixme);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Task> list() {
    return this.tasks;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Task add(@RequestBody Task task) {
    this.tasks.add(task);
    return task;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Task delete(@PathVariable String id) {
    Task t = this.tasks.stream().filter(task -> task.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
    this.tasks.remove(t);
    return t;
}
}
```

Comment: Configure your server to show the actual error message.

Comment: The problem is with the server-side, not the client-side.

Comment: Slaks i dont know how to do that? do you mean see the json data, it is: [{"id":"809b7e46-98b2-43a0-98ec-38d89f925a1e","name":"Fix me."}]

Comment: @yasgur99 Please show the html template (tasks) your are using. The error says your template is invalid.

Comment: @Xinzoop I added it in the question

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf requires valid XML, and on the line you posted you have:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
```

The & isn't a valid XML character, so you need to either surround your javascript with CDATA like this:

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[

... javascript here ...    

// ]]>
</script>
```

Or else replace them with `&amp;&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed ';' at the end of

```
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState === 4) {
    if (http.status === 200) {
    addTaskToList(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: i changed that it did nothing :(

Comment: You missed </html> at the end?